# how to retrieve a particular xml tags value using c#

Tags: c#, xml

i need to read the value of a particular value in an xml tag, of he solutions i tried i could only find that to get a value of a tag element ,i need to traverse from root element to the child element.is there an optiion where i can directly select a tag and get its value.

In the below xml exa,i need to get 123456 value from the xml using c#.
Ex:-

```
<ForwardActionRequest xmlns:auth="test" xmlns="http://www.test">
    <auth:Authentication>
        <auth:AuthenticationData>
        <auth:AuthenticationKey>test</auth:AuthenticationKey>
        <auth:Username>test</auth:Username>
        <auth:Password>test</auth:Password>
        </auth:AuthenticationData>
    </auth:Authentication>
<SearchOrderReference>
    <Reference>123456</Reference>
    <AllocatedBy>test</AllocatedBy>
    <Description>test</Description>
</SearchOrderReference>
```

Comment: Take a look at XDocument and the Descendants method

Comment: Hi Liath, Using VS 2005 which doesnt support LINQ

Comment: In that case I'd suggest putting the version of .NET in your question - most people will assume a fairly recent version.

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(yourXMLText);
string value = doc.Element("SearchOrderReference").Element("Reference").Value;
```

Please note that I haven't tested this code.

I also encourage you to read more about [LINQ to XML here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308960.aspx).

Comment: Hi Saeed, im using visual studio 2005 which doesnt support linq.

Comment: Then you should use [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx), because it exists in .NET 2. However, you also have the option of using regular expressions.

Comment: yes im using xmldocument object.have loaded the xml into the object.i want to know how can i get the value of a particular tag value

Comment: Then `doc.GetElementsByTagName("Reference")[0].Value;` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode() to pass in an XPath that will describe the node you want and then extract the value. Use this prototype as you are using namespaces:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b(v=vs.110).aspx

Read about how to instantiate an XmlNamespaceManager() and initialize it with the relevant prefix (it needs not be what you have in the xml itself), then issue the following request:

```
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/t:ForwardActionRequest/t:SearchOrderReference/t:Reference");
```

Given that you associate "t" with "http://www.test".

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize the xml content into a class and directly get the value of the element or you can use LINQ to XML to retrieve the element value,

XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(XMLContent or XMLPath);
string=doc.Element("SearchOrderReference").Element("Reference").Value;

Answer (score 0):

From your post using VS 2005 you can try the XML Reader which reads the XML from string. Here is an example.

```
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
{
    reader.ReadToFollowing("SearchOrderReference");
    reader.ReadToFollowing("Reference");
    string r = reader.ReadInnerXml();
}
```

Comment: I typecasted xml object into a string variable and retrieved the exact value using substring method.
        string str = strTest.Substring(strTest.IndexOf     ("<SearchOrderReference>"),strTest.IndexOf("</SearchOrderReference>")-strTest.IndexOf  ("<SearchOrderReference>") );
        string strRef = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("<Reference>"), str.IndexOf("</Reference>") - str.IndexOf("<Reference>"));
        string finalRef = strRef.Replace("<Reference>","");.

Thanks For all your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(yourXMLText);
var node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//SearchOrderReference[@Reference='123456']");
```

Then extract node's attribute to get the value of reference tag.